# how to convert object into array on javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

If I have an object like this :

```
var fix_num : 0;

kwT: {
        "0": 10.2,
        "1": 0,
      }
```

How can I convert it to an array with this format :

```
[fix_num.key_of_object_kwT, fix_num.key_of_object_kwT, ... etc]
```

Result must be like this :

```
[0.0, 0.1]
```

Thank you in advance, I'm stuck here.

Comment: That's not an Object. `var obj = { kwt:{'0':10.2,'1':0} }` would be object `obj` with `kwt` as a property that is also an Object. What is that?

Comment: A [*simple search*](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+convert+object+to+array) may have answered your question.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the keys and use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to alter the keys.

```js
var fix_num = 0;

var kwT = {
    "0": 10.2,
    "1": 0,
};

var result = Object.keys(kwT).map(function (key) { return fix_num + "." + key });
console.log(result);
```

Other option is a simple for-in loop and push the value into a new array.

Answer (score 0):

I like the above more though...

```
var fix_num = 0,
    obj = {
        "0": 10.2,
        "1": 0
    },
    arr = [];

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key){
    arr.push(fix_num + "." + key);
});

console.log(arr); //[ '0.0', '0.1' ]
```

Comment: Your `map` creates an array filled with `undefined`, and then discards it. You should use `forEach` instead.

Comment: Using `map` is correct, but you want to **return** the value from inside the `map` callback.